# Non-Response Rate: Outlier data, does it count?

Tags: non-response

I'm currently doing an undergraduate stats module and we're being asked to calculate the response rate and many people are conflicted by whether or not the excluded outlier data would constitute as a non-response.

Personally I do not think that it would constitute non-response as technically, they did respond.

However, some others think that it would constitute non-response because the only reason for their data to be excluded would mean that the values they answered with were considered nonsensical in a way.

[image: Figure 1]

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just say that the data was excluded because of quality issues? What difference does it make if you call it non-response or not?

Comment: @Tim we were specifically asked to calculate the response rate, so we have to make a decision either to include or exclude it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to report both rates - otherwise it will not be possible for a reader to judge the validity of the study.